# ModelChoiceField not being populated with the previously entered value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've created a ModelChoiceForm that is being dynamically populated with all of the flatpages that do not have a value for FlatPageExtras.child_of.  To do this, I have the following set up:

Forms.py:

```
class FlatPageExtrasForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FlatPageExtras
        fields = ['head_content', 'endbody_content', 'new_page', 'child_of']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FlatPageExtrasForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['child_of'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = FlatPage.objects.filter(sites = Site.objects.get_current()).exclude(flatpageextras__child_of__isnull=False),widget = forms.Select, required = False)
```

views.py:

```
def edit(request, flatpage_id):
    site = Site.objects.get_current()
...
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.has_key("update"):
            return update(request, page)
...
    else:
        flatpageextras_obj, result = FlatPageExtras.objects.get_or_create(flatpage=page)
        form = FlatPageForm(instance=page)            
        form_flatpageextras = FlatPageExtrasForm(instance=flatpageextras_obj)
```

Template:

```
{{ form_flatpageextras.child_of }}<label for="id_child_of">Page on your site you would like this to appear under. </label></p>
                {% if form_flatpageextras.child_of.errors %}
                    {{  form_flatpageextras.child_of.errors }}
                {% endif %}
                <p class="help-text">If a page is selected, that will be the parent site for this one.  Leave blank if you would like no associations</p>
            </div>
```

This all works...almost!  When I go to the provided template, the drop down is there, correctly showing the available flatpages, except it always shows as blank initially, even though the field is being properly saved to whatever the selected page is.  How can I get the drop down to correctly show the current choice?

Comment: Maybe you can define empty label like this self.fields['child_of'].empty_label = (Select)

Comment: Adding an empty label just has it default to the empty label, despite actually being updated in the database with each selection.